# eror 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: object, variables, set

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyAdjacentCell()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range
    Dim emptyCell As Range, searchValue As Range
    
    ' Open the first workbook and set the worksheet and column to search for empty cells
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\POC\Desktop\De soto arbeit\Kopie von 20231004_PrNummernMatrix_.xls")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("PrNummern-Matrix")
    Set col1 = ws1.Range("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    
    ' Open the second workbook and set the worksheet and column to search for the value
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\POC\Desktop\De soto arbeit\Kopie von 20220930_Vgl_PRNR_FAS_Fahrzeuge.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set col2 = ws2.Range("C:C")
    
    ' Loop through each empty cell in the first column
    For Each emptyCell In col1.Cells
        ' Get the adjacent cell value in the same row
        *searchValue = emptyCell.Offset(0, -1).Value*   -------**Object variable or With block variable not **set
        
        ' Search for the value in the second column
        Set foundCell = col2.Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        ' If a match is found, copy the adjacent cell value to the empty cell
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            emptyCell.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next emptyCell
    
    ' Close both workbooks without saving changes
    'wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

searchValue as string
```